# Laravel 5.1: Many-to-many alongside one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm making an event RSVP app where a user creates an event (or events), and can allow other users to manage the event with them. Each event also has an owner (the user that created the event).

My Goal:

**How I can create an event, assign its owner and also add it to the `event_user` pivot table at the same time**

These are my current relationships...

**Event Class** - `App\Event`

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'owner_id');
}

public function managers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**User Class** - `App\User`

```
public function owns()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'owner_id');
}

public function manages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
}
```

*Removed migrations as not really relevant.*

**Updated methods - as per Mina Youssef's suggestion.**

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$event = new App\Event(['name' => 'Event 2']);

$event = $user->owns()->save($event);

$user->manages()->attach($event->id);
```

This now assigns the owner and attaches the user to the event in the pivot table correctly.

How can I join the `owns` and `manages` methods together when creating an event so I don't have to call them separately?

**UPDATE: Added `boot` event to `AppServiceProvider`**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::created(function ($event) {
            $event->owner->manages()->attach($event->id);
            return true;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the variable $site?

Comment: Sorry that should read, $event, I was playing around with some stuff earlier and copied the wrong part. I'll update it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add entries to Many to Many relationship, then use the `attach()` method

So you can do the following:

```
$user->manages()->attach($event->id);
```

However, this works after saving the $event model, to get its id.

To trigger the attach method directly, you can do the following in your `AppServiceProvider`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::created(function ($event) {
            $event->owner->manages()->attach($event->id);
            return true;
        });
    }
```